# Azure AD add App Role in App Registration using REST API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-rest-api

is there a way to add `Add role` to existing  `App registration` in `Azure Active Directory` using REST API/CLI/Powershell?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the Azure CLI you can specify application roles within the manifest.json. Here an example:

```
[
  {
    "allowedMemberTypes": ["User"],
    "description": "Approvers can mark documents as approved",
    "displayName": "Approver",
    "isEnabled": "true",
    "value": "approver"
  }
]
```

The corresponding CLI command:

```
az ad app create --display-name mytestapp --identifier-uris https://mytestapp.websites.net --app-roles @manifest.json
```

[Source.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#az-ad-app-create-examples)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. The way Martin is suggesting is not what you asked for as that only allows the creation of an app.

You need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-update. However in order to update the list of roles you will need to fetch the existing first and append them to the role(s) you want to add.

A better option is to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. This allows you to use the REST and is much easier to use.